# Signed bytes from Schnorrkel library throws Bad Signature error

Tags: rust, extrinsic, subxt, signing

Hey I have some call data which is similar to [this](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/da507fa6d29a1583f1ef0e6cdfd0760290f67f7e/subxt/src/tx/tx_client.rs#L167).

I am signing it using [schnorrkel libaray function function](https://github.com/w3f/schnorrkel/blob/master/src/sign.rs#L203). as `secret.sign_simple(&[], msg)` where `secret` is a [Keypair](https://github.com/w3f/schnorrkel/blob/master/src/keys.rs#L692) and `msg` is in bytes.

Then I create a multisignature using

```rs
let sig_slice: &[u8] = &sig_bytes;
let sig = Signature::try_from(sig_slice).unwrap();
let multisig = MultiSignature::Sr25519(sig);
```

where `&sig_bytes` in bytes returned by signing and if I add that signature to make a extrinsic bytes e.g. [here](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/da507fa6d29a1583f1ef0e6cdfd0760290f67f7e/subxt/src/tx/tx_client.rs#L186)

I get error `Transaction has a bad signature.`

And if I send the same extrinsic using subxt and pass the signer as `PairSigner<SubstrateConfig, sr25519::Pair>` it works fine. But I can't use this pair sign function when signing a msg because of nature of architecture. I have to use an independent lib something more generic.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually we need a context string for substrate signatures

```
let context = schnorrkel::signing_context(b"substrate");
Signature::Sr25519(secret.sign(context.bytes(msg)))
```

and then we can use the sign function which gives us a valid signature.